# @Injection is not working for CDI bean

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I have a CDI bean where I'm using @ConversationScoped. When I try to do an @Inject for the Conversation object, I get a NPE.

```
  @ConversationScoped
@Named("customerbean")
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;    

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ba");
    private EntityManager em;
    private Customer customer;
    boolean disabled;    

    public CustomerBean() {
        beginConversation();
        customer = new Customer();
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        disabled = false;
    }

    private void beginConversation() {
        if (this.conversation.isTransient()) {
            this.conversation.begin();
            return;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

I have the beans.xml file (although empty) in the WEB-INF directory. The exception looks like this:

```
INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java
.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdap
ter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientPr
oxyProvider.java:102)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolve
r.java:115)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResol
ver.java:96)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.util.ForwardingELResolver.getValue
(ForwardingELResolver.java:49)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELR
esolver.java:176)
```

Comment: How do you create/access the `CustomerBean` in your code?

Comment: @Erhan: Conversation is a reference to a special managed bean as required per JSR 299 specification.

Comment: @Thorbjörn - I reckon the OP is unaware of the lifecycle of CDI beans and simply mixed up the initialization of his bean. But more code will certainly help

Comment: @Aaron: I use it in my xhtml files by accessing it. I assume it gets initialized by the framework upon first access. However, my "problem" started appearing after I realized that even though I have ConversationScoped, it's behaving as if it has Session scope. Upon further reading, I understood that I have to execute the begin()-method in order for the framework to understand that I want to have a long-running bean. Now when I try to inject the Conversation into the bean, I get the NPE.

Comment: @Jan: You are right, I am new to CDI/JSF. Ive previously used Struts/Spring for other projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must not create a CDI bean using `new`, nor use a constructor for any sort of initialization logic.

The reason behind this is that CDI beans (like EJBs, Spring beans, JSF beans) have an independent lifecycle and are managed by the relevant container. You cannot rely on the "traditional" understanding of when (and how often) `new` will be called. Use producers to create new beans, and use `@PostConstruct` for any logic to be performed after creation.

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/) should give you a good start with CDI. Feel free to post further questions :)

Comment: Isn't this more like a comment?

Comment: At least it wasn't intended to be like one. I'm referring to the fact that the OP has put logic into the constructor, which is completely wrong and lead to the assumption that he has probably not understood the basic principles of CDI...

Comment: OK, I moved out the initialization logic to a postconstruct method. It seems to be initializing now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Jan says, you're adding logic into the constructor. Injection doesn't happen until after the constructor is called.