# Unable to inject a CDI bean in Primefaces LazyDataModel implementation class

Tags: java, primefaces, cdi, jsf-2.2

Any CDI bean I inject in the implementation class of `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel`, turns out null. The lazy model implementation class itself is a CDI `@Named` bean with scope `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`. It looks like this:

```
    @Named("myLazyModel")
    @ViewScoped
    Class MyLazyModel extends LazyDataModel implements Serializable {

    public MyLazyModel() {

    }

    @Inject
    AnotherCdiBeanClass injectedObj;

    public AnotherCdiBeanClass getInjectedObj() {
        return injectedObj;
    }

    public AnotherCdiBeanClass setInjectedObj(AnotherCdiBeanClass anotherCdiBeanClassObj) {
        this.injectedObj = anotherCdiBeanClassObj;  
    }


    public void someMethod() {
       getInjectedObj(); // Its NULL, why?
    }


}
```

I did get a warning in eclipse from Java while injecting in lazymodel implementation bean class. Warning was something like that **the lazymodel class bean can not proxied by the container as it does not contain non-private no-arg constructor and the bean is not a normal scoped bean**(something like that).

There is another problem, in the LazyDataModel implementation class, I have set the rowCount to the size of the actual data list's dynamic size (size after filtering in grid). But then after instantiating the lazymodel implementation class outside in some CDI bean gives me a rowCount of zero.

`new MyLazyModel(actualDataList).getRowCount()` -> 0

Upon debugging I found it does contain the complete actual data list but rowCount is still zero.

I needed on the go `rowCount` of the filtered rows as I type and filter them on a primefaces grid so that I can dynamically update an outputLabel with the currently filtered grid's rowCount value.

```
int currentRowCount = actualDataListInLazyModelClass.size();
```

I will be updating the outputLabel like this:

```
org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.update("myForm:recordCountLabel");
```

But before that I need to set property of an injected bean (View's backing bean) with the rowCount value but the injected bean itself turns out null as said before.

```
getInjectedObj().setNoOfRecords(Integer.toString(currentRowCount));
```

// NULL POINTER because getInjectedObj() is null

Sorry if I have described things more or less due to limitations at my end.

Comment: These are in fact two separate questions. The topic has not much to do with the real cause. Keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Accordingly, I have changed the question title.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong ViewScoped. For CDI on JSF 2.2 it should be `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` and if you are on JSF 2.0/2.1 but are using CDI (you 'should'), you can use the [OmniFaces Viewscoped](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped)

See also

- [Why are there different bean management annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations)
- [@ViewScoped bean recreated on every postback request when using JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251176/view-scoped-bean-recreated-on-post-with-jsf-2-2-4)

Comment: There is a problem. In my project javaee-api-6.0.jar is being used. It does not contain the class javax.faces.view.ViewScoped. It was introduced in Java EE 7. Is there really any workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, for JSF 2.0/2.1 you can use the [OmniFaces ViewScoped](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) (Edited my answer accordingly)

Comment: But I am using Primefaces 5.0. So maybe I can not use OmniFaces as well. Am I right? As I am bound to use JBoss EAP 6.3.2 and Java EE 6 API. So, so far I have been using java.faces.bean.ViewScoped as supported by JSF 2.1.28 from within EAP 6.3.2 modules.

Comment: Plus, the combination of javax.inject.Named and javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped is working well in all other CDI beans of the application. But in LazyDataModel implementation class, this combination is not working and all the injected beans are null.

Comment: Are you using DeltaSpike? That automagically fixes the bean scoping things. Otherwise I cannot imagine it works.

Comment: Oh, and doing `new MyLazyModel` will **not** cause injection to take place… see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368888/injection-is-not-working-for-cdi-bean

Comment: Upon injecting MyLazyModel in another class, I get warning 'cdi-ambigous-dependency' and while deploying I get org.jboss.weld.exception.DeploymentException.. Any idea?

Comment: Show code, full stacktrace and PLEASE answer my question about DeltaSpike